# Cordova ios app is'nt loading index.html page after splashscreen with no console errors. Can see header loaded not index.html. loads fine on android

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

The cordova app is emulating fine on IOS safari browser and android emulator.

The loading issue is only on IOS simulator and IOS device. Safari console has no errors. Need help on things that I can relook to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

@Debuggers you can try to remove iOS platform and install it again. Maybe you missed some steps after/before build the app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried that quite a few times but didnt work.

Comment: @Debuggers can you show your code on github to reproduce the problem?